# Using A $_GET Variable inside a function for database insert?

Tags: php, arrays, get, insert

hopefully someone can shed some light on a problem I am having.

I have a form which is used to add a comment to a page;

```
    <?php if(app('current_user')->role != 'user'): ?>
        <div class="leave-comment">
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                <h5><?= trans('leave_comment'); ?></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment-text"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                 <div class="controls">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="comment">
                        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                        <?= trans('comment'); ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p><?= trans('you_cant_post'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This uses ajax to load the following case;

```
case "postComment":
    echo app('comment')->insertComment(ASSession::get("user_id"), $_POST['comment']);
    break;
```

Which loads;

```
public function insertComment($userId, $comment)
{
    $userInfo = $this->users->getInfo($userId);
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $this->db->insert("as_comments", array(
        "posted_by" => $userId,
        "posted_by_name" => $userInfo['username'],
        "comment" => strip_tags($comment),
        "post_time" => $datetime,
        "FK_DappID" => 1
    ));

    return json_encode(array(
        "user" => $userInfo['username'],
        "comment" => stripslashes(strip_tags($comment)),
        "postTime" => $datetime
    ));
}
```

The comments are used on a page called view.php, I have a variable which is set from the URL of htis page called $_GET['ID'].

**SO..**

How can I change the "FK_DappID" => 1 which is in the array to be inserted to the database, to the value of $_GET['ID'] ?

I have tried using "FK_DappID" => $_GET['ID'] but it does not work..

Any help would be GREATLY appriciated.

Thanks, B.

EDIT: Index.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//comment button click
$("#comment").click(function () {
    //remove all error messages
    asengine.removeErrorMessages();

    var comment = $("#comment-text"),
         btn    = $(this);

    //validate comment
    if($.trim(comment.val()) == "") {
        asengine.displayErrorMessage(comment, $_lang.field_required);
        return;
    }

    //set button to posting state
    asengine.loadingButton(btn, $_lang.posting);

     $.ajax({
        url: "ASEngine/ASAjax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action : "postComment",
            comment: comment.val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //return button to normal state
            asengine.removeLoadingButton(btn);
            try {
               //try to parse result to JSON
               var res = JSON.parse(result);

               //generate comment html and display it
               var html  = "<blockquote>";
                    html += "<p>"+res.comment+"</p>";
                    html += "<small>"+res.user+" <em> "+ $_lang.at +res.postTime+"</em></small>";
                    html += "</blockquote>";
                if( $(".comments-comments blockquote").length >= 7 )
                    $(".comments-comments blockquote").last().remove();
                $(".comments-comments").prepend($(html));
                comment.val("");
            }
            catch(e){
               //parsing error, display error message
               asengine.displayErrorMessage(comment, $_lang.error_writing_to_db);
            }
        }
    });
});

});
```

EDIT: Ajax.php

include_once 'AS.php';

$action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
    case 'checkLogin':
        app('login')->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        break;

```
case "registerUser":
    app('register')->register($_POST['user']);
    break;

case "resetPassword":
    app('register')->resetPassword($_POST['newPass'], $_POST['key']);
    break;

case "forgotPassword":
    $result = app('register')->forgotPassword($_POST['email']);
    if ($result !== true) {
        echo $result;
    }
    break;

case "postComment":
    echo app('comment')->insertComment(ASSession::get("user_id"), $_POST['comment']);
    break;

case "updatePassword":
    app('user')->updatePassword(
        ASSession::get("user_id"),
        $_POST['oldpass'],
        $_POST['newpass']
    );
    break;

case "updateDetails":
    app('user')->updateDetails(ASSession::get("user_id"), $_POST['details']);
    break;

case "changeRole":
    onlyAdmin();

    $result = app('user')->changeRole($_POST['userId'], $_POST['role']);
    echo ucfirst($result);
    break;

case "deleteUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    $userId = (int) $_POST['userId'];
    $users = app('user');

    if (! $users->isAdmin($userId)) {
        $users->deleteUser($userId);
    }
    break;

case "getUserDetails":
    onlyAdmin();

    respond(
        app('user')->getAll($_POST['userId'])
    );
    break;

case "addRole":
    onlyAdmin();

    respond(
        app('role')->add($_POST['role'])
    );
    break;

case "deleteRole":
    onlyAdmin();

    app('role')->delete($_POST['roleId']);
    break;


case "addUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    respond(
        app('user')->add($_POST)
    );
    break;

case "updateUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    app('user')->updateUser($_POST['userId'], $_POST);
    break;

case "banUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    app('user')->updateInfo($_POST['userId'], array('banned' => 'Y'));
    break;

case "unbanUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    app('user')->updateInfo($_POST['userId'], array('banned' => 'N'));
    break;

case "getUser":
    onlyAdmin();

    respond(
        app('user')->getAll($_POST['userId'])
    );
    break;

default:
    break;
}

function onlyAdmin()
{
if (! (app('login')->isLoggedIn() && app('current_user')->is_admin)) {
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your ajax

Comment: @RyanTuosto added

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting your ajax with `type: "POST"` so the data will be available in your PHP in the `$_POST` variable.

Since it looks like you're adding a comment this is the correct request verb to use so change to `"FK_DappID" =>$_POST['ID']` in your insert method and be sure to add `ID` to the `data` you are POSTing in your AJAX:

You should create a hidden form input `<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?= $_GET['ID'] ?>" />` and then get the value from this input to send in your AJAX POST request.

```
data: {
  action : "postComment",
  comment: comment.val(),
  ID: $("#post_id").val()
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I am passing the variable ID as so, 

http://localhost/Login/view.php?ID=1

Then getting it on the view page using $PK_DappID = $_GET['ID'];

Can I get the variable using POST instead of GET?? 

Thankyou for the input!

Comment: sure just use $_POST['ID'] instead, also you will need to add that to the data you are sending through the ajax

Comment: Hi Ryan, really appreciate the help and I hope you can excuse my lack of coding knowledge. 

How would I pass the variable to a new page using POST rather than GET? I thought GET was the only way to bring a value from another page. 

If I use $PK_DappID = $_POST['ID'] on my view page it does not bring the value over from the other page.

Thanks, Brad.

Comment: No worries, I think its a common point of confusion.  You DO want to use GET to pass the data to a post view page.  Then to add a comment to that post you want to use a POST request and pass the ID to add the comment to the correct post.  A common way of exchanging this data is through a hidden form element where you echo the $_GET value, then retrieve it in javascript in order to send back through the POST request in ajax.  I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: I've added the hidden input to the page, & ID: $("#post_id").val() to the ajax request. I have also set "FK_DappID" => $_POST['ID'] in the insert method. No luck as of yet, I've noticed I have forgot to add the ASAjax page in my code, I will add it now, does the an extra parameter need adding there too? 

Thanks again.